# workaround for iptables limit multiport rule

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-20.04

I have many ports to block, but iptables multiport rule has a restriction and only allows a maximum of 15 ports.

```
severalports="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16"
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports $severalports -J DROP
iptables v1.4.21: too many ports specified
```

I'd like to know if there is any way to create a custom rule to bypass the maximum 15 ports limit (so I don't have to split the rule). thanks

PD: Ports 1:16 is just to explain the idea. Actual ports are not in sequence

Comment: Why do you think it's called `restriction` ? You can recompile `iptables` with a patch of yours to allow more, but this WILL affect performance.

Comment: Do you really need to select ports, rather than just blocking all traffic from the IP address?

Comment: btw: `iptables v1.4.21` doesn't seem very `Ubuntu 20.04`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implicit [`-m tcp`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#tcp), `-m udp` (and sctp etc.) all accept port range parameters. So your current example could be simplified into simply:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1:16 -j DROP # -m tcp is implicitly loaded if omitted anyway
```

---

It's the same for [`-m multiport`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#multiport) except a range eats two slots:

> `multiport`
>
> This  module  matches  a  set of source or destination ports.  Up to 15
> ports can be specified.  A port range (port:port) counts as two  ports.

So if there are up to 7 ranges (+1 single port), you can do something like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 1:5,10:50,6666 -j DROP
```

---

If you plan on an arbitrary high number of ports without adding a high number of rules, you can switch to using [*ipset*](http://ipset.netfilter.org/) (which also requires using the [`ipset`](https://manpages.debian.org/ipset/ipset.8) tool) and a [`set`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#set) match:

```
ipset create portlist bitmap:port range 0-65535 #or narrower if known in advance
for i in $(seq 1 1000); do ipset add portlist $i; done
```

EDIT: actually the specific case above (all values in one single range) can also be simplified by using a range syntax in *ipset* (support might depend on version though) instead of the loop if needed. Won't change the set result:

```
ipset add portlist 1-1000
```

Single *iptables* rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m set --match-set portlist dst -j DROP
```

A bitmap should have O(1) lookup: constant (and what could matter: very fast) time.

*ipset* can be dynamically changed while in use:

```
ipset del portlist 22
```

even [from the packet path](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#SET) if really needed.

It offers a lot of other list types (like `hash:ip,port`), most of them hashed. They can be loaded with hundred of thousand of entries and still keep a fast lookup, and help having simple and generic rules.

Comment: 1:16 No. it is only an example. It is just to explain the idea. The ports are not in sequence. , but your idea of ipset like me. I'm going to try it

Comment: I know it's only an example which happens to work here. My answer is to be complete and helpful for other persons too, in case they didn't know that sometimes they don't even need multiport (nor ipset)

Comment: Your answer is good and I am trying to test the ipset solution. But it still hasn't worked for me. I keep trying. Once I finish I inform you

Comment: thanks ipset is the solution for workaround

Comment: Note that to make the `ipset` upload as fast as possible, you should consider using the `ipset-restore` command instead. See the manual page for details. Use `ipset-save` to see the file format.